# Producing every digit from a radix through a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

To get this out of the way - I am not a mathematician, but I have encountered an interesting problem that I think is very obvious, thus it has definitely been expressed before, but I do not know how to call it or how to look for solutions to it. I call it "the fishnet problem", as it happened when I was planning a fishnet-like pattern.

Abstraction:
Suppose you have a round piece of fabric with a number of holes ($x$) on its edge and an arbitrarily long string. Using regular gaps, pass the string through every hole without repeating any hole.

As math (I suppose):
For any radix, find a sequence of numbers that, when iterated over their multiplications, produce every possible digit as their last digit.

Simply put, if you iterate over multiplications of $3: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15,\dots]$, you will see every digit of the decimal system as the last digit until you reach $30$. (in terms of abstraction, for ten holes, passing the string through every third hole will pass it through every hole) This applies to any number that ends with $1, 3, 7,$ or $9$.  Meanwhile, for Base-$5$, each number lower than $5$ fulfills this requirement (and subsequently each number that isn't a multiple of $5$ does as well). I was not able to pinpoint any characteristic that would solve this for any radix, I am only suspecting that these digits are always symmetrical (if $x$ is a solution, then $base - x$ is a solution as well).

Comment: Is it just that the number of holes and the size of the gap are relatively prime?

Comment: I think so, too @BenedictW.J.Irwin